# Xcode Workspace "Internal error: missingPackageDescriptionModule"

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

After updating Xcode to version 13.2 i can't build my project anymore. I have a strange error "Internal error: missingPackageDescriptionModule" related to my Workspace file.

It's definitely related to SPM because Xcode is not loading SPM packages also. I tried to "Reset package caches", "Resolve package caches" and also "Updating to latest package caches" but after all of these operating nothing happens. Deleting derived data, cleaning didn't help too...

[image]

I tried also to resolve packages from Terminal using `xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies` but I get error message:

```
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: The directory /Users/ptocicki/Developer/KFC/kfc-ios also contains the legacy project 'project.pbxproj' - ignoring it and using 'KFC.xcodeproj'.

xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
  Internal error: missingPackageDescriptionModule"
```

Comment: Same thing over here... I just can't believe such a HUGE bug would go out the door. Have you managed to find a fix?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue. I'm running Xcode 13.2 (via App Store) on macOS Big Sur 11.6.2 on a 2019 16" MBP. I did not see this bug in the Xcode 13.2 release candidate from last week.

Comment: I reinstalled Xcode, but unfortunately that not helped too

Comment: I tried my project on an M1 Pro MBP running macOS Monterey 12.1, same issue.

Comment: Same here https://stackoverflow.com/q/70342174/10050675

Comment: I'm also seeing that when I create a brand new project, and try to add an SPM package like Alamofire, it gets stuck at the step "Verifying Alamofire... Preparing to validate...". So it looks like it might be more of a widespread SPM issue.

Comment: I found an ongoing discussion on this issue in the Apple Developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504

Comment: I downloaded XCode 13.1 using the XCodes app and it all works fine

Comment: This is one of the worse I saw in a long time. You spend hours waiting the damn thing to finish downloading and installing, only to find out that if you preferred to use SPM, you'll need to start **all over again**. This time with a **10GB(!)** download (also, download speed is really poor).

Comment: @bauerMusic If possible always try to download Xcode from Apple portal (NOT AppStore), because updating from AppStore always takes o lot more time. I also recommend [Xcodes](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/XcodesApp).

Comment: @Peterses I guess so, but I think the AppStore can do incremental updates, the full version is kind of huge. (Nice App at Xcodes!)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Fixed on v13.2.1 and you can [download from here](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.2.1/Xcode_13.2.1.xip)

---

## Explaination

This [bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504) is reported and the v13.2.1 AppStore version but As [ Apple suggest here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504?answerId=698142022#698142022), you should download the Xcode manually from the developer center

## Manual download of any Apple developer software

> ✅ The always working and preferred workaround!

Download directly from Apple:

- **[Latest Release version](https://developer.apple.com/download/release/)** or
- **[Latest Beta version](https://developer.apple.com/download/)** or
- **[Any version you need](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)** and all other downloadable contents

Then extract and move it where you like. This has so many benefits compared to AppStore updates. (like the ability to resume download, not replacing the old one, not wasting hidden directories and etc.)

**Note that** you should use safari to download it.

---

#### ⚠️ Important note for developers like me!

> ## The page you’re looking for can’t be found.

If you `The page you’re looking for can’t be found` message, you may need to use a **VPN** if you are in a country that the US sanctioned like mine. Because Apple is blocking some IP address ranges.

Comment: Your direct download link for Xcode 13.2 is not working for me. There's a public link if someone wants : https://xcodereleases.com

Comment: Downloading Xcode 13.2 worked for me, also the direct download links works as of now, Thanks 

Comment: glad it only takes hours until its downloaded and unpacked 

Answer (score 36):

Apple is aware of the issue.

> We're currently investigating this issue — thank you to those who have
> filed bug reports so far. To workaround this issue, please re-download
> Xcode 13.2 directly from the Downloads page.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504?answerId=698142022#698142022

Comment: I can confirm that after downloading Xcode from apple portal, the error is gone.

Comment: I first moved the current XCode to Trash before installing the one from the portal. Working fine for me now.

Comment: And they wonder why more Mac developers don't deploy to the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 13):

- If you’re using Swift packages either standalone or as dependencies in an Xcode project or workspace, the Mac App Store version of Xcode fails during package resolution with the error “Internal error: missingPackageDescriptionModule.” (86435800)

Workaround: Download Xcode 13.2 directly from the [Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode%2013.2).

Comment: This has worked for me 

Comment: Error returned after only one day even with the version from the Dev-portal. 

Comment: I was facing issue with Xocde 13.2. Updating to 13.2.1 worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just got the issues late at night after Xcode updated on its own while I was working on my project, which was not a cool surprise. It appears to be affecting all dependencies. You are not alone in this it's affecting everyone. I did what they recommended and downloaded Xcode directly from the Apples developer site and it fixed all my issues super happy right now!!!!!!!

Comment: downloading from 13.2 RC or 13.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

XCode was updated to 13.2.1 at 12/19 which fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_2-release-notes

> If you’re using Swift packages either standalone or as dependencies in an Xcode project or workspace, the Mac App Store version of Xcode fails during package resolution with the error “Internal error: missingPackageDescriptionModule.” (86435800)
>
> Workaround: Download Xcode 13.2 directly from the [Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode%2013.2).

<s>Seems local package still working. So there is a temporary solution: We can download the dependencies then add them to the project as local paclages.</s>

Answer (score 0):

Please update to **Xcode 13.2.1**.
[image]

If not, download **Xcode 13.2** from the [Apple Developer website](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.2/Xcode_13.2.xip).

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Xcode 13.2 to 13.2.1 from App Store fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: @EricAya The difference is that others have suggested downloading manually whereas I have mentioned updating from App Store.

Comment: Well, this is the same solution: update Xcode. I don't see how this is different. :)