# Xcode 13.2 - Internal error : Missing Package Description Module

Tags: swift, xcode

Just updated Xcode to 13.2 via Mac App Store.

I installed the additional components, and my project won't compile anymore : Xcode just tells me `Internal error: missingPackageDescriptionModule - Resolving Package Graph Failed` when attempting to build. None of the Swift packages used within my app seems to build, because "Package resolution errors must be fixed before building".

Already attempted to restart Xcode, update macOS, clean derived data, reset Swift package caches and update package versions to no avail.

Guess I'll try re-installing Xcode but... does anyone else have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I have same issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341912/xcode-workspace-internal-error-missingpackagedescriptionmodule. I'm re-installing Xcode now.

Comment: update to Xcode 13.2.1 which is released on 17th Dec, that will solve this problem

Comment: cleaning derived data helped me

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**EDIT:** Xcode 13.2.1 version fixes this issue and can be downloaded from the Mac App Store.

**Old Answer:**

Apple has responded:

> We're currently investigating this issue — thank you to those who have
> filed bug reports so far. To workaround this issue, please re-download
> Xcode 13.2 RC directly from the More Downloads page.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504

Comment: I can confirm, that after downloading the Xcode from apple developer the build works fine now.

Comment: I downloaded the the app from developer portal and it's not working

Comment: Version 13.2 from 12/13 installs SPM dependencies no problem for me. https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Comment: @zumzum which version?

Comment: I installed the Xcode version 3 times and it would work for a bit and then it would stop working. I figured out later that I needed to disable the automatic Mac app store update option. The Mac App Store would install the broken Xcode 13.2 version over the one from developer portal and break things. What a mess. I'm good now.

Comment: It worked at first, and now after few days of working with project, it started showing same error again.

Comment: @Jonauz Maybe you have the same problem as @zumzum? The Mac App Store might be automatically updating your Xcode to the broken version. Try disabling automatic updates from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Xcode 13.2.1 - problem is fixed

Comment: I have Xcode 13.2.1 and the problem still exists!!!