# Xcode 13.2 package issues

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

As recommended by Apple, I've downloaded and installed the Xcode 13.2 RC to replace the one from the App Store and I still have problems. My package that compiles on Xcode 13.1 fails to compile with multiple errors on 13.2. The errors are all related to dependencies (other packages).

Is there any other workaround?

At this point 13.2 is useless. Hopefully this will be fixed quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did it for me today:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
$ softwareupdate --all --install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Xcode 13.2 RC or downloading from the App Store, try downloading Xcode from Apple Developer.  This worked for me.

[Xcode Download Page](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

There is an ongoing discussion and [another SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70346642/3856812).