# xcode stuck while installing version 13.2 on macOS montery 12.1

Tags: xcode, flutter, react-native, cross-platform

Downloaded new Xcode version 13.2 from AppStore, it was getting stuck in installing for more than 16 hours.

How can get rid of this, while stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple is aware of this issue. You just need to download **manually** from the apple developer

**Xcode 13.2 Release [note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_2-release-notes)**

## [Download Xcode 13.2](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.2/Xcode_13.2.xip)

And now it's worked perfectly. And also follow this SO discussion [section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341912/xcode-workspace-internal-error-missingpackagedescriptionmodule/70346642#70346642)

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Worked for me. Mine was also stuck at 'downloading 12.64GB of 12.64GB' for hours. Downloded xcode 13.4 from developer account. Installation took less time than appstore.

Comment: If anyone stumbled here, just know that you can also increase the speed of the unzipping with `xip -x Xcode_13.2.xip` to skip validation.

Comment: This advice goes for any Xcode version. There's hardly a good reason to use the excessively slow App Store to upgrade Xcode. Manual installation allows you to actually see what's happening at each step, and you don't wonder why the spinning wheel keeps spinning for hours with no end.